# Best practices | Session data with persistent identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-identity

I'm currently developing an application using .Net Core 5 and I am using Identity for the user management.
While connecting, the user can check the "remember me" checkbox ( again, this uses Identity ).

When a user connects, I also load other useful data that I will using at multiple places in the application. This data is then preserved inside a session.

The problem I have is that, if a user closes his browser and then opens it back, he will still be connected but he won't have his session data.

My question is: What is the best thing to do in that situation ?

- Should I load the useful data every single time I need it ? Even if it requires multiple complex calls to the database ?
- Should I detect when a user is connected but without any session data and then load it back ?

Is there any other solutions I should consider ?

Comment: Have you considered LocalStorage? This data is saved across browser sessions. It's quite normal to store user data there and then erase it only when the user logs out (or you get a 401 due to e.g. expired token).

Comment: Last one. Try to get the specific data from the session, if it fails, create it, store it in session, and return it. This could be achieved via a scoped service and properties for every session value.

Comment: I also thought about implementing the IAuthorizationFilter interface which would allow me to check for the session values everywhere I use the [Authorize] attribute. Do you think that would be a good idea ?

Comment: the session data is stored in the server's memory, fetched by session id which is stored in session cookies in the browser. So basically the session data is lost if you lose the session id (deleted). And here you see this quote *Session cookies are deleted when the browser session ends* from this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state

Comment: Yes I know that, please read the question again.

Comment: Have you tried Cache instead of Session? Cache will remain as long as it is not yet expired even the session has ended.